# adding a scope to an _ids Active Record attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Location that has_many Item class. items have a scope for is_enabled. I can do

```
loc=Location.find(1)
loc.items.is_enabled
# and
loc.item_ids

# how would I do?
loc.item_ids.is_enabled
```

thx

Comment: One option is `loc.items.is_enabled.map(&:item_id)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
loc.items.is_enabled.map &:id
```